# Visual Studio 2012 on thin client environment

Tags: visual-studio-2012, thin-client

We want to teach students to develop apps using Visual Studio.

Is it possible to run Visual Studio 2012 Express in thin client environment (Windows 7 x64)?

Comment: Did you already try once to install it?

Comment: This thread looks exactly the same: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8b1e2a64-5706-4c30-8325-e062ebcb07cf/installing-and-running-vbnet-2012-in-a-thin-client-terminal-server-environment

Comment: running....
only problem is cannt run same app on diffrent thin client error is port is already in use